# How do you make labels in an AngularJS application editable without code changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, internationalization, translation

I am building an AngularJS-based application that is localized to a handful of different languages and uses ng-translate. So far, I have one big JSON file that contains all translated strings required.

My coworkers have a marketing background. They are not comfortable editing JSON directly and I am not comfortable letting them do it.

I would build a simple UI to edit the strings for l10n, store them in a DB and make them accessible via a REST service. But I imagine this must be a common problem. I have not found any out-of-the-box solution, so do you know one?

Comment: no different than any other data ... has to be stored server side somewhere and any updates must be sent from client to server

Comment: I understand that. What I was looking for is if there's some existing solution that people use for this.